# How do I send people my app beta?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, adhoc, ad-hoc-distribution

Whenever I've asked people about how to send out a beta through email, they've always told me "Oh, it's easy. You just export the IPA, then send everyone the link." I've done this myself as a tester. I tap the link, and it installs. Easy as that.

And now I can't find out how to do that.

For me, I export, and attach the link in an email to myself, and it forwards me to safari, with an "Open with..." prompt. I can't figure out how to get it to install.

I'm not interested in TestFlight or anything that involves more complication. I just want to send people my build, and can't figure out which part I'm getting wrong.

Comment: testflight involves more complication? it's integrated with itunes connect, you just archive and submit the app and all the testers receive a notification with the update if they have testflight app

Comment: It is more involved in that the testers need to be added to iTunes Connect or if external testers the app must go through app approval.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming (and I hope you don't) jailbreak targeted devices:

With a basic Apple developer licence, you'll need to add devices UDID into the provisioning profile you built your app with. Using a third-party service is a great solution (Crashlytics, TestFlight).

If you have an [Enterprise Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) plan, you can build your app with your certificate and install it on a device **without adding its UDID before** - that's what you need. Once you built the app, you'll just have to host the generated *.ipa* on a web-server with HTTPS and send the direct link to your customer. Please find the official documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/gettingstarted/).

Comment: Note: Enterprise apps can only be distributed to employees of the company.

Comment: Yeah, I expect @Andrew to read the Apple documentation and use this only for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a webserver for this, and one that support HTTPS.
[Here](http://readwrite.com/2010/12/15/apple-best-kept-secret-how-to-do-ad-hoc-installs) is a link how to do this. Of course, this only works if you know the user's UDIDs beforehand, or use an In-House distribution profile.

Comment: Posting a link to the answer is unacceptable for this site. Please include whatever information is needed to solve this _in your answer_ such that readers to not have to go elsewhere to complete their answer. Links which provide additional information beyond what is required to answer the question are highly welcomed. The reason for this requirement is that external sites can move or disappear without notice, rendering an "answer" useless. Putting the required information here means the question and answer can persist as long as the answer remains correct.